# Maven, Spring Data, MongoDB and Apache Solr integration

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, solr, spring-data

I want to build an application using Maven, Spring Data, MongoDB and apache solr. I don't know from where to start. I am having knowledge of Maven, Spring-Data, MongoDB and a bit of solr. Later on want to add Spring-MVC too Any guidance would be appreciated. Has anyone tried this ??? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this link http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/
, where the writer has described pretty much what you need minus Solr. I think this should get you going. Then, you could search for Solr Maven dependencies and add it to your pom and use it accordingly in your project.